# Apache Commons ZipArchiveOutputStream breaks upon adding Filenames with non ASCII Chars

Tags: java, scala, apache-commons

I am using an org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream to add files coming from a Subversion repository.
This works fine as long as I do not use German Umlauts (ä,ö,ü) or any other special characters in the filename.
I am wondering what would be the fastest way to make it accept non ASCII chars?

```
def zip(repo: SVNRepository, out: OutputStream, url: String, resourceList: Seq  
       [SVNResource]) {
  val zout = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(out))
  zout.setEncoding("Cp437");
  zout.setFallbackToUTF8(true);
  zout.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true);
  zout.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(ZipArchiveOutputStream.UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.NOT_ENCODEABLE);
  try {
    for (resource <- resourceList) {
      addFileToStream(repo, zout, resource)
    }
  }
  finally {
    zout.finish
    zout.close
  }
}

private def addFileToStream(repo: SVNRepository, zout: ZipArchiveOutputStream, resource:SVNResource): ZipArchiveOutputStream = {
  val entry = resource.entry
  val url = YSTRepo.getAbsolutePath(entry)
  if (FILE == entry.getKind.toString) {
    val file = new File(url)
    val zipEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry(file, url)   
    zout.putArchiveEntry(zipEntry)
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val fileprops = new SVNProperties()
    repo.getFile(url, -1, fileprops, baos)
    IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray), zout)
    zout.closeArchiveEntry
  } else if (DIR == entry.getKind.toString) {
    if (resource.hasChildren) {
      val dirProps = new SVNProperties()
      val entries = repo.getDir(url, -1, dirProps, new java.util.ArrayList[SVNDirEntry])
      for (child <- SVNResource.listDir(repo, entries.toList.asInstanceOf[Seq SVNDirEntry]])) {
        addFileToStream(repo, zout, child)
      }
    }
  }
  zout
}
```

Comment: What does "breaks" mean? Does it throw an exception? If yes, please post the exception. If no exception, does it create a file that isn't readable by itself? Or isn't readable by another application?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: The zip is written to archive.zip. After unpacking it I expect a file named über.pdf. The filename gets displayed correctly using IZArc under WINXP. I can also open it with WindowsCompressedFolders but the filename is wrong, it contains readable characters though. Under Linux I can NOT open the file because the name contains an unreadable character.

Comment: It sounds like the zip is completely valid then, you just need to investigate alternative programs for extracting from the file.

Comment: The archive is streamed from a public website. The filenames should be readable by most programs.

Comment: hi take look this for chinese file name zip compress probem http://stackoverflow.com/a/21521784/1194578

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting

```
UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.NOT_ENCODEABLE
```

to

```
UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.ALWAYS
```

Filenames are now displayed correctly using Linux-Unzip, Windows-Compressed-Folders, IZArc and WINZIP.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it sounds like the real problem is with the Linux `unzip` program and/or the encoding supported by your Linux filesystem. One solution is to pass the `-U` option to unzip, which will escape any Unicode characters in filenames.

That said, I also recommend removing the following lines when you write your ZIPfile:

```
zout.setEncoding("Cp437");
zout.setFallbackToUTF8(true);
zout.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true);
```

And replace them with the following:

```
zout.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

This should result in the highest portability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the filename through URLEncoder first: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

That will ensure that the zipped filename is pure ASCII

When reading it back out, use URLDecoder to recover the full UFT-8 character set: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I need control over the extaction process? The zip gets streamed to the user's browser.