# .zip file created by Java doesn't support Chinese(utf-8)

Tags: java, compression, zip

I want to create a .zip file using Java(jdk, ant.jar or commons-compress).

But if the ZipEntry's name contains non-English(eg. Chinese, Japanese), it will display unreadable code in WinRAR or Windows Compress(commons-compress display correctly in WinRAR).

Who can help me!!!

Comment: Sure it's not just a problem with the program you're using to view the files?  Zipping something shouldn't be dependent on the characterset.

Comment: @Alison, it do. The filename charset varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit one of the [Top 25 java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4244499).

Good news is this is already resolved. Bad news it it is fixed only in JDK7. See [this entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/non_utf_8_encoding_in) for details.

Alternativlly, you can use [Arcmexer](http://www.javamex.com/arcmexer/) (readonly).

Comment: It says JDK 7 in the blog post.

Comment: fixed. and added an alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I still cannot find a solution, but maybe this can solve my manager. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

try this by using apache commons compress,

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream;
public class ZipFiles {  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       ZipArchiveOutputStream zipOut = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("测试.zip"));
       zipOut.setEncoding("Cp437"); // This should handle your "special" characters
       zipOut.setFallbackToUTF8(true); // For "unknown" characters!
       zipOut.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true);                               
       zipOut.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(
       ZipArchiveOutputStream.UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.NOT_ENCODEABLE);
       zipOut.putArchiveEntry(new ZipArchiveEntry("测试.xml"));
       zipOut.putArchiveEntry(new ZipArchiveEntry("test.xml"));
       zipOut.closeArchiveEntry();
       zipOut.flush();
       zipOut.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to [7-Zip-JBinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net) it's a Java wrapper for 7zip.